# NoMethodError in Researches#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I try to make an application on rails similar to the official tutorial http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html, but instead of articles, I have used the researches. Where's my fault if I, when you try to view a list of all the research, I receive an error. Where is my mistake?

```
undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
```

ResearchesController

```
class ResearchesController < ApplicationController

    def new
  end

  def show
    @research = Research.find(params[:id])      
  end

    def index
        @researches = Research.all
    end

    def create
    @research = Research.new(research_params)

    @research.save
    redirect_to @research
  end

  private
    def research_params
    params.require(:research).permit(:name, :period_of_execution, :cost)
  end
end
```

index.html.erb

```
<h1>Listing of our researches</h1>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name:</th>
    <th>Period of execution:</th>
    <th>Cost:</th>
  </tr>

  <% @researches.each do |research| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= @research.name %></td>
      <td><%= @research.period_of_execution %></td>
      <td><%= @research.cost %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write:

```
<td><%= research.name %></td>
<td><%= research.period_of_execution %></td>
<td><%= research.cost %></td>
```

Because you are currently referencing the variable declared here:

```
<% @researches.each do |research| %>
```

Answer (score 0):

In you view you need to refer to 'research', not '@research'.

It's a small thing.